# What does Request[" "] mean?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I came accross this unusual thing, and I'm not sure what it is.

There is a place in the code where I found :

```
if(IsPostBack == false)
{
    string strInterior = Request["xmlString"];
}
```

I have one javascript page which is using xml http object ajax (The project is in *asp.net 1.1*)

This xmlString is a variable in javascript which contains a XML format string and passes it like this:

```
var objTrim = createXMLHttpObj();
var xmlString = "<UrlXML>";
xmlString += "<ID>" + id + "</ID>";
url = url + "abc.aspx?trim=";       
objTrim.open("POST", url + escape(TrimRecordsValue) , true);
objTrim.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  

objTrim.send("xmlString=" + xmlString);
```

I am not sure what this `Request["xmlString"]` means .This is called in the code behind the page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xmlString` value is being posted to the server, so it's availible to be read in the servers [`Request.Form` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

The `Request["string"]` is an indexer operator that searches through QueryString, Form, Cookies, and ServerVariables collections.

In your case it is finding the value in the `Form` collection.

Comment: The `Request` indexer looks through QueryString, Form, Cookies, and ServerVariables collections http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETParamsCollectionVsQueryStringFormsVsRequestindexAndDoubleDecoding.aspx

Comment: This is called inside if(IsPostBack == false){ Request["xmlString"] }..SO does that mean this xmlString is created at each page load.

Comment: @RatanSharma It is posted to the server in your javascript.

Comment: @RatanSharma `Request["xmlString"]` _pulls_ the value from the HttpRequest collections listed above - it does not _create_ anything.

Comment: @DStanley .. Thanks..I am just wondering when and how the HttpRequest happened and this xmlString is created with its value.

Answer (score 1):

It's a syntax shortcut for the [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item.aspx) property of the `HttpRequest`, which will look for an item with that string as it's key in either the  `QueryString`, `Form`, `Cookies`, or `ServerVariables` collections.

Answer (score 1):

objTrim.send("xmlString=" + xmlString);

You are doing Ajax Post to code behind.
xmlString is a query string id. To get the value of the querystring, you need to use
Request["xmlString"] or Request.QueryString["xmlString"]

By this way, we send value from client side to serverside through either Ajax Get or Post.
We can use "Get", if the value length is small enough to be fitted in one network packet.

You can send multiple values amso -
Here is an e.g,
objTrim.send("xmlString=" + xmlString + "&anothervalue=blablabla);

string str_xmlstring = Request["xmlString"];
string str_anothervalue = Request["anothervalue"];

Hope, this clears all confusion.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Every time a form is sent to the server (every time you ***post*** something on a page), a collection of values is sent with the header in the form of `Request.Form`. So Request["something"] will get the "something" index of that collection.